# droid 2 lock screen problems

Tags: lock-screens, motorola-droid-2

I just broke my *Droid DBA* so im switching back to an old phone (*Droid 2*). But my lock screen is not responding properly: it shows, I grab the lock, but it doesn't unlock (or it just doesn't register).

Does anybody know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the touch sensor is broken, had the same issue with an old Motorola milestone: only the left third of the screen was detecting events (and rightmost pixel line). I could unlock it with a 2 finger gesture (tap&hold left, tap& hold right side, then release left. The slider then jumped to the right and unlocked. The milestone has a hardware keyboard which i then used to further navigate